# [Vue warn]: Computed property "axios" is already defined in Data. at <App>

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I know similar questions already present in stackoverflow, but I still can't understand how to solve this. I am having the warning(look in the title) in my console.

[image: look at the warning]

You can reproduce the warning by the following code

```
//index.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios';

const app = createApp(App)
app.__proto__.axios = axios
app.use(store)
app.mount("#app")
```

##App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="TodoList">
    <p v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">{{ todo.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fillItems");
  },
  computed: {
    todos() {
      return this.$store.getters.todos;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

##store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        todos: []
    },
    getters: {
        todos(state) {
            return state.todos
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        FILL_ITEMS(state, payload) {
            state.todos = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        fillItems({ commit }) {
            this.axios
                .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
                .then(res => commit('FILL_ITEMS', res.data))
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add axios to [`app.config.globalProperties`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) in order to access it inside any child component :

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.axios=axios
```

in child component use `this.axios`

but you couldn't access it inside the store context because `this` in the actions refers to the store instance, so you should import axios inside the store file and use it like :

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        todos: []
    },
    getters: {
        todos(state) {
            return state.todos
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        FILL_ITEMS(state, payload) {
            state.todos = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        fillItems({ commit }) {
            axios
                .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
                .then(res => commit('FILL_ITEMS', res.data))
        }
    }
})
```

or you could assign `axios` to the store instance (It's not recommended specially with typescript) :

```
const app = createApp(App)
store.axios = axios
app.use(store)
app.mount("#app")
```

[image: Edit vue 3 ts (forked)]

Comment: Thanks... since I want to show a tiny example, I made the store.js a single file but there are multiple modules files, which uses axios, writing axios in every file is not feasible. Is there a work around?. My solution is working but this warning is bugging me

Comment: You could add `axios` to store like `store.axios=axios;app.use(store)` then use it with `this.axios`

Comment: Thanks.. you can update your answer with the above comment. And I will mark your answer. Its is working as I intended.

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3, you can create app globals for components using provide/inject:

### Providing

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios';

const app = createApp(App)
app.provide('axios', axios);  // Providing to all components here
app.use(store)
app.mount("#app")
```

### Injecting

In the options API:

```js
export default {
  inject: ['axios'];   // injecting in a component that wants it
}
```

In the composition API:

```js
const { inject } = Vue;
...
setup() {
  const axios = inject('axios');   // injecting in a component that wants it
}
```

**Edit:**
I answered too fast (thanks @BoussadjraBrahim), you're not asking about components, but I'll leave that answer too.  If you just want to use `axios` in a separate module, you can use it like any import:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

and use `axios` instead of `this.axios`

Comment: Good suggestion; But he couldn't access `this.axios` inside the store instance

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - You're right, I didn't even pay attention long enough to notice he's not asking about a component

Comment: you could edit this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-forked-q67kd?file=/src/store.ts) and see that  `this` refers to the store instance not to the app one

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim No, it's obvious.  I just didn't scroll his question enough to see he's asking about Vuex and not a component.

Comment: He could pass it as action payload like `this.$store.dispatch("fillItems",this.axios);` but this a bad practice specially when he has multiple actions that use axios

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Not just bad, that would be a terrible practice :)

Comment: Thanks... since I want to show a tiny example, I made the store.js a single file but there are multiple modules files, which uses axios, writing axios in every file is not feasible. Is there a work around?. My solution is working but this warning is bugging me

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no way to use an import in a disconnected module like that without importing it in each module that will use it